# Image won't appear when used as a background

Tags: html, css

I have this folder "student" in my main folder, called "main".
And I have php file in this address "main/student/home.php".
which uses CSS in this address "main/config/style.css".

I want give a image on my "home.php", image on "main/images/1.jpg".

But when I wrote this on my style.css the image won't appear.

This is my style.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #c09854 url(images/img1.jpg) repeat-x;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #3B3B3B;
}
```

I am really confused bout this, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in css path should be specified relative to style sheet file so specifying like this

```
 background: #c09854 url(../images/img1.jpg) repeat-x;
```

should help.

Comment: When referencing a file outside of the current folder "../" will tell the browser to step back one level to find the correct folder. The more "../" you use, the farther back the browser will search. Hope this helps to understand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should give styles in the following format

```
background:#ffffff url('../images/img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be this:

```
background: url(main/images/1.jpg) repeat-x #c09854;
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
background: url(../images/1.jpg) repeat-x #c09854;
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote different urls and names of files: "main/images/1.jpg" and "images/img1.jpg". Maybe there is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you load the image on the page in straight HTML? that will tell you if your path is correct, the image exists, and permissions etc.

The css looks okay so I assume its an issue with the image path.

you can also try breaking out the background tags like this:

background-image:url('images/img1.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;